# How to create solution add-ins in Visual Studion 2008

Tags: add-in

I'am trying to create Solution Add-in with the help of this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms165621(v=vs.80)

However, I've been loosing. I follow those instructions carefully, but I think that something important is missing from my view. So, this is the order of what I am doing, and what I am planning to get:

1. Create default Add-in solution with the help of Add-in wizard. Since it is planning to be a solution add-in, I remove the XML declaration file.
2. Check "register is as a COM object" in the properties tab.
3. Use regasm to register the add-in as a com object in the windows registry.
4. And this is where the troubles begin. As I understand, I must write the following code from the link into my OnConnect event of Add-in class file. Ok, I've done that. Build project, and everything is fine.

BUT I don't understand how to associate this add-in with solution. MSDN says:
"When Visual Studio loads a solution, it first examines the solution (.sln) file to see if it references add-ins. If so, it loads them and calls the same IDTExtensibility2 methods as a regular Visual Studio add-in."

When I'am trying to debug add-in, I've open my external solution, but nothing fires in my OnConnect event, untill I've checked the add-in in Add-in manager window.

Is it intended to be so, or I am missing something important in this steps. As I understand from descriptions, solution's add-in OnConnect must be fired at the moment, when IDE opens any solution file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that this won't help you much now, but might help someone else. I have faced the same problem last week, trying to make add-in that will load and be active only with one solution. Ended up on the same MSDN page and stuck on the same point :).

To make solution add-in follow the link provided in the question. Follow all the points listed except point number five - skip adding following line of code in your add-in logic:

```
EnvDTE.AddIn addin = _applicationObject.Solution.AddIns.Add("MyAddin.Connect", "MyAddinName", "My add-in description", true);
```

Open text editor and edit .sln. Input these lines at the end of .sln file in the **global** section:

```
Global
(...)        
    GlobalSection(ExtensibilityAddIns) = postSolution 
        MyAddin.Connect = 1;My add-in description;MyAddinName
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

This is exactly what _applicationObject.Solution.AddIns.Add() inputs in .sln file
Now when this solution is loaded into visual studio, while loading solution it will also load this add-in. One more thing to add here:
when add-in is loaded this way, **connectMode** param passed to the OnConnection function has value **ext_ConnectMode.ext_cm_Solution**.

Hope it helps :)